# VBA Loop through column and append to a cell

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, append

This is my first time writing anything in VBA- I'm trying to loop through a column (RRlist) and if the value is more than 20, add info about that cell from its row into another cell (rcomments). I want all of the info to add into that cell so it's a list. 
When I try to run this code, nothing happens in my spreadsheet.

```
Option Explicit
Public rcomments As String
Public RRlist As Range
Public RRcell As Range

Sub WrittenMacro()

rcomments = ""
Set RRlist = Range("G33:G420")
For Each RRcell In RRlist
    If RRcell.Value > 20 Then
         rcomments = rcomments & "CUSIP " & RRcell.Offset(, -5).Value & ", "      & RRcell.Offset(, -4).Value & "has a return of " & RRcell & "; "
    End If
 Next RRcell

 End Sub
```

Comment: You never write rcomments anywhere, where it is supposed to go?

Comment: @AlexK. I'm not totally sure what you mean by that. rcomments is a cell in my spreadsheet that I renamed.

Comment: No, rcomments is a string variable (`Public rcomments As String`). You put text into it and then do nothing with it.

Comment: Then after the loop: `Range("rcomments").Value = rcomments` (Just because your variable is called the same thing as your named range does not link them together in any way)

Comment: @AlexK. thanks- so that line should put the string into my cell, right? I added it after the loop and I'm still not getting anything.

Comment: Have you used the named cell tool to create a cell named "rcomments"?  If you `msgbox rcomments` after the loop is there data?

Comment: @AlexK. yeah I used the named cell tool. And when I do the msgbox rcomments I get the first iteration through the loop